# How would you say "A butterfly is landing on a flower." in Latin?

Tags: word-request

How would you say "*A butterfly is landing on a flower.*" in Latin? Specifically, which word would you use for "*to land*"?

In a song called "*Aeromiting u vrtu*", sung by Oliver Dragojević, the author uses the very-Latin-sounding word "*aterira*" for that. Was there a Latin word such as "*atterrare*" (from "*ad*" + "*terra*") for "*to land*"? I cannot find it in a dictionary, but I doubt the songwriter made that word up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would guess what you heard in the song is based on the French verb [*atterrir*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/atterrir). *Il atterrira* means he/it will land. This verb was invented by the French and has no direct Latin equivalent, as far as I can see, although all its components are Latinate, of course.

In Latin I would use *considere* or *assidere*, which are both used of birds and bees (did not find an example for a butterly), e.g. Livy, [Ab urbe condita 7, 26](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/livy/liv.7.shtml#26):

> Romano corvus repente in galea consedit
> *a raven suddenly sat down on the Roman's helmet*

Or Sueton, [Tiberius 14](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/suetonius/suet.tib.html#14):

> aquila numquam antea Rhodi conspecta in culmine domus eius assedit
> *an eagle never before seen on Rhodos sat down on the highest top of his house*

So you could say: **Papilio in flore assidit.**

Comment: By the way, I don't know how it works in Croatian, but a German speaker would not bat an eye at the dative *Romano*; however, English speakers are possibly scratching their heads why I translated this as "the Roman's." Think like, "it happened to the Roman that a raven sat on the [= his] helmet."

Comment: Well, it's possible that the dialectal Croatian word in that song comes from French. The city of Split, where Oliver Dragojević lived, was under the French occupation for much of the 19th century. No wonder some words in that dialect come from French.

Comment: One could also consider the influence on Croatian of the Italian *atterrare* (itself a calque from the French),

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Could "in Romano galea" be translated as (ablative) = "on the Roman helmet"? Would your choice be called a "dative-of-possession"?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel The dative is probably good here for all Slavic languages, definitely for Czech.

Comment: @tony At least in the modern languages I know the word in dative is not bound directly to the noun helmet, it is bound directly to the verb. Similarly in German "Er ist mir auf den Fuß getreten." The collocation is https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemandem_auf_die_F%C3%BC%C3%9Fe_treten "Literally, he stepped on the foot *to me*."

Comment: Would *in florem* work better than *in flore*?

Comment: @Figulus: Is that because "in florem" = "into the flower", giving: "The butterfly lands inside the flower."?

Comment: @tony Well, *Romano galea* wouldn't work, would it? I believe this is called the dative of reference, by the way. (The distinction from an "indirect object" is not clear cut.)

Comment: @Figulus No, these words are generally constructed with a place where. See L & S ...

Comment: @tony Not really. I was just thinking that the English verb *landing* is a verb of motion, so I wrongly assumed the same for its Latin counterpart. After studying the examples Sebastian gave us, I can see that is not exactly right. I still can't claim to understand why not, though.

Answer (score 9):

The verb insido+Dative.(I edited because of the corrector)
Vergilius gave us a good example: "“apes floribus insidunt,” Verg. A. 6, 708"